# error 404 page acting crazy

Tags: javascript, html

I am using `.htaccess` to make a 404 page show up if a file is not found. I use javascript `window.location` to get the page the user requested and read it out onto the page. But the page is loading over and over again. It is [here](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/weedle.html). The page is flickering, it is refusing to load. Anyone know why?
HTML:

```
<h1 style="display:inline; font-family:crimson;">
  Sorry<span style="font-family:crimson;">,</span>
</h1> 
<h2 style="display:inline; font-family:crimson;">The page you requested: 
<span style="color:red">
<script>
var location = window.location;
document.write("<a href='" + location + "'>" + location + "</a>");
</script>
</span> was not on our site. That's all we know.</h2>
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* 404.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: your question is missing the htaccess you are referring to, add it to the question

Comment: I think it's looping because you don't have any conditions set. Try setting a condition in htaccess before your RewriteRule...?

Comment: But before i used the javascript, it worked perfectly. I didn't make any change to the `.htaccess`. It is the javascript that is causing it.

Comment: the link does work. why shouldn't it, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to declaring a variable called `location`, but since the script is in a global scope, the variable will be mapped to the already existing member of window object `window.location` so what you are actually doing is

```
var window.location = window.location;
```

which means you are assigning to the window location, and that causes a navigation.. simply rename the variable.

```
<script>
var sURL = window.location;
document.write("<a href='" + sURL+ "'>" + sURL+ "</a>");
</script>
```